# how to divide large loaded task in multiple background worker?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

how to make more than one background worker .. which first one get 100 record from db and when first complete second one start and get another 100 record from db and append it to first loaded 100 record and another BG until l loaded all my data from db ?

Comment: Why is the second one starting after the first one has finished? If you want that, just use one worker.

Comment: Yes, sounds like you just need one worker which loops.

Comment: why would you like to fetch records letter?
Do you want to bind gridview?